# Azure Kubernetes Stuck on Failed (Running) After Attempted Node Pool Addition - Quota Exceeded Issue

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with my Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I recently attempted to add a new node pool to my AKS cluster, and encountered a "Quota exceeds" error during the process. Since then, my AKS cluster has been stuck in a state where it shows "Failed (Running)".

The error message I received during the node pool addition was as follows:

```
(CreateVMSSAgentPoolFailed) Code="OperationNotAllowed" Message="Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: uksouth, Current Limit: 10, Current Usage: 10, Additional Required: 4, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 14. Submit a request for Quota increase at [Quota Approval Link] by specifying parameters listed in the ‘Details’ section for deployment to succeed. Please read more about quota limits at [Quota Documentation Link]"
```

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I executed the command az resource update --ids  as suggested in the error message. However, I received the same error again.

The error message indicates that I need to request a quota increase due to exceeding the approved Total Regional Cores quota for the location "uksouth". The details specify that the current limit is 10, current usage is 10, and additional required cores are 4, with a minimum new limit of 14.

I followed the provided link to request a quota increase, but I'm still stuck with a failed AKS cluster. I'm quite new to AKS and Azure, so I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could provide guidance on how to resolve this? Is there something specific I need to do after requesting the quota increase?

Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Code: CreateVMSSAgentPoolFailed
Message: Code="OperationNotAllowed" Message="Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: uksouth, Current Limit: 10, Current Usage: 10, Additional Required: 4, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 14. Submit a request for Quota increase at [Quota Approval Link] by specifying parameters listed in the ‘Details’ section for deployment to succeed. Please read more about quota limits at [Quota Documentation Link]"**

Comment: your subscription may be configured to limit the number of cores for a region. If you attempt to deploy a virtual machine with more cores than the permitted amount, you receive an error stating the quota has been exceeded.equest a quota increase [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-resource-quota?tabs=azure-cli#solution) make sure req should approved quota has been increased and you should be able to add the new node pool to your AKS cluster